# Data cleaning in python/pyspark: Conditional (for/if) exits prematurely before all the code is applied to the data

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a problem which looks similarly to this: I have three groups of salary classes, High/Medium/Low. On each group I need to perform some operations (adding columns, cleaning, ...). However, some groups (in my code example High and Low) share several identical cleaning operations. In order to avoid code duplication for them, I wrote a for loop where I want to apply some cleaning on "High", some on "Low", and then some code on both (the line with the word "PROBLEM). The category "Medium" does not share any of that cleaning, so it is separate.
Each one of the results I need to write in a separate df for post processing.

I realized after half a day trial and error that the code in the for loop exits after the if block is over without applying the shared code to the df. Is there a way to modify this? If not, how would this problem be best solved?

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import os
import sys
os.environ['PYSPARK_PYTHON'] = sys.executable
os.environ['PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON'] = sys.executable
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('SparkByExamples.com').getOrCreate()

data = [
    ("1", "High", 10000),
    ("2", "High", 10000),
    ("3", "Medium", 1000),
    ("4", "Medium", 1000),
    ("5", "Low", 100),
    ("6", "Low", 100)]
columns = ["ID","Salary_Level", "Salary"]
my_data = spark.createDataFrame(data = data, schema = columns)
```

```
def cleaning_function(df, name):

    high_and_low = [name]

    for name in high_and_low:
        # This one only for high
        if name == "High":
            df = df.filter(df["Salary_Level"] == "High")
            df = df.withColumn("Bonus", F.lit("Denied"))
        
        # This one only for Low
        elif name == "Low":
            df = df.filter(df["Salary_Level"] == "Low")
            df = df.withColumn("Bonus", F.lit("Approved"))

        # PROBLEM: This one I want to apply for both High and Low after they were preprocessed above, but its not working
        df = df.withColumn("Extra_Column", F.lit("Processed"))
        
    # And this one is a separate 
    if name == "Medium":
        df = df.withColumn("Extra_Column", F.lit("Processed"))
        df = df.withColumn("Bonus", F.lit("Special Treatment"))

    return df
```

```
result_h = cleaning_function(my_data, "High")
result_m = cleaning_function(my_data, "Medium")
result_l = cleaning_function(my_data, "Low")
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the if statements for high and low processing, you are filtering the input df by salary level, and then applying the extra logic. In that way, you will never have both low and high levels since you have *filtered* them.

Also, to do exactly what you expect your code to do, you can do it in this way:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
    
my_data = my_data.withColumn("Bonus", when(my_data.Salary_Level == "High", F.lit("Denied"))
                                 .when(my_data.Salary_Level == "Low", F.lit("Approved"))
                                 .otherwise(F.lit("Special Treatment")))
    
my_data = my_data.withColumn("Extra_Column", F.lit("Processed"))
```

Output:

```
+---+------------+------+-----------------+------------+
| ID|Salary_Level|Salary|            Bonus|Extra_Column|
+---+------------+------+-----------------+------------+
|  1|        High| 10000|           Denied|   Processed|
|  2|        High| 10000|           Denied|   Processed|
|  3|      Medium|  1000|Special Treatment|   Processed|
|  4|      Medium|  1000|Special Treatment|   Processed|
|  5|         Low|   100|         Approved|   Processed|
|  6|         Low|   100|         Approved|   Processed|
+---+------------+------+-----------------+------------+
```

To get separate df's:

```
high_df = my_data.select("*").filter(my_data.Salary_Level == "High")

low_df = my_data.select("*").filter(my_data.Salary_Level == "Low")

medium_df = my_data.select("*").filter(my_data.Salary_Level == "Medium")
```

Comment: This produces the desired result for the example. But unfortunately it will not scale for the real problem I have. That one has much more transformations going on for many more (sub)-datasets. So I would like to keep the code in a function so it is easier to debug and expand.

Comment: So what issues are you having? Because I just ran your code and it is showing nothing unusual. All three salary range df's have the extra column, meaning it applies to both high and low, as expected. If you want, I can copy it to my answer, but it's the same code that is giving a different output, which I doubt it's the case.